# Using a mutable array to retrieve an array saved to NSUserDefaults and changing the value

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults, mutability

Values returned from `NSUserDefaults` are immutable, even if you set a mutable object as the value.

There is a problem about this that confuses me.

I save an `NSArray` (immutable) into user defaults with `setObject:forKey:` and then synchronize.

I delete the code for saving and I use an `NSMutableArray` to get the value I saved, via `objectForKey:`

I do some mutable operation on the mutable array. I use `[[userDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:]` to retrieve the array, and it's changed by my operation, and I synchronize.

But when I run the program again, the array is not changed!

Can I use the mutable class to receive a immutable class? It can be changed, and it appears in memory, and the value retrived from the user defaults was changed also. I don't know why. I synchronized, but the plist file was not changed. I don't know why.

code:

```
    //NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //NSArray *arr = @[@"1",@"2"];
    //[ud setObject:arr forKey:@"arr"];
    //[ud synchronize];
    NSMutableArray *arr = [ud objectForKey:@"arr"];
    NSLog(@"before %@",arr);
    NSLog(@"%@",[arr class]);
    [arr isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]];
    [arr removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"after %@",arr);
    BOOL ans = [ud synchronize];
    NSArray *arr2 = [ud objectForKey:@"arr"];
    NSLog(@"retrieve from ud %@",arr2);
```

console:

```
2013-12-02 11:42:46.791 NSUserDefaultsDemo[24447:303] before (
1,
2)
2013-12-02 11:42:46.792 NSUserDefaultsDemo[24447:303] __NSArrayM
2013-12-02 11:42:46.792 NSUserDefaultsDemo[24447:303] after (
2)
2013-12-02 11:42:46.793 NSUserDefaultsDemo[24447:303] retrieve from ud (
2)
```

Comment: You should not assume anything about the mutability of objects returned by NSUserDefaults. Whatever you get from NSUserDefaults should be considered immutable. Whatever it is in reality is an implementation detail.

Comment: And you saved those changes to NSUserDefaults too?

Comment: @Julien THX , I want to figure out rather than the other

Comment: @juniperi  the data in UserDefaults was not changed

Answer (score 1):

You don't save your changes to NSUserDefaults as I thought.

This code works:

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"Object 1", @"Object 2"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arr forKey:@"testArr"];

NSMutableArray *mArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"testArr"]];
[mArr removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mArr forKey:@"testArr"];
```

Synchronize don't save your changes if you don't use setObject:forKey: method first. And btw, you don't need to call synchronize manually, only if you want to make sure that preferences gets saved when you quit your application etc.

Comment: and I Know that.  So I am curious about mechanism

Comment: hi,guy    when I use a NSArray to receive the value of [objectForkey]

Comment: and I print by [ class] ,the result is _NSArrayM. It's ridiculous

Comment: NSArray *arr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"arr"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[arr class]);

Comment: Try it on 10.9, with an app using the 10.9 SDK. It should be properly immutable now. On older systems, things were mutable in some cases, but as you found out, trying to mutate them didn't actually work.